# Android ImageView alignment in LinearLayout

Tags: imageview, alignment

I have a simple android app. In an activity I added LinearLayout(horizontal. There I put three different ImageView objects. I want them to be : one on left, one in center, one on right side.
This is xml code:

```
<LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/javtokas"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_lefthorizontal="true"
            android:src="@drawable/javtokas" />

         <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/jankunas"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerhorizontal="true"
            android:src="@drawable/jankunas" />

         <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/lipkevicius"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_righthorizontal="true"
            android:src="@drawable/lipkevicius" />

    </LinearLayout>
```

I tried a bunch of different options but no one worked well. How can I achieve what I want?

Comment: This has been asked so many times. There are 100+ questions on how to do this, and even more answers.

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for 
android:layout_weight

All your image view should have 
android:layout_width='0dp'
android:layout_weight='1'